# Why is it not recommended to host receive endpoints in a web application using MassTransit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, endpoint, servicebus, masstransit

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 application (based on nopCommerce). I want to use MassTransit to communicate with another application that is used for inventory management, billing, etc. It would be easier if I could add receive endpoints directly into the web application and not have to create a Windows service for that. But the [MassTransit documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/configuration.html) says it is not recommended and there is no explanation as to why that is.

> **MassTransit in a web application**
>
> Configuring a bus in a web site is typically done to publish events,
>   send commands, as well as engage in request/response conversations.
>   Hosting receive endpoints and persistent consumers is not recommended
>   (use a service as shown above).

Does anyone know the reasoning behind it? Is it not safe to add receive endpoints in a web application? Will they not work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hosting endpoints in a web application is not recommended because web applications often restart for various reasons. These reasons are typically outside the control of the application itself.

While using a standalone Windows service is highly recommended, as long as the bus is properly started and stopped using the `Application_Start` and `Application_End` methods, it can be okay if you have no other options available.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll start by hosting the receive endpoints in the web app and switch to a Windows service if there are any problems.